# How to validate EditText?

Tags: android

I am doing one SMS App.. in which i am trying to validate edittext(i.e. if user will not enter the phone number then it will show please enter the number), but it is not executing those part.. Please check it and give me some suggestion....My code is here.. Thank you in advance..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnSend;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtSMS; 
    String phoneNo, SMS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSend=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        txtPhoneNo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
        txtSMS=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                phoneNo=txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                SMS=txtSMS.getText().toString();

                if(phoneNo.equals(" ") || phoneNo == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Enter the number !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                MyAsync ma = new MyAsync();
                ma.execute();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Wait!", "Sending...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, SMS, null, null);

            } catch (Exception e) {             
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            pd.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: you can set input type of edittext `android:inputType="number"`. So you can enter only numbers and you use `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)` to validate.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the following code to determine whether the user entered anything—

```
phoneNo.equals(" ") || phoneNo == null
```

Firstly, when the user keeps the `EditText` empty, it will be a 0-length string "" and NOT a space " ", which you're testing for.

Secondly, why are you making the `null` check? Is it possible that your layout won't have that `EditText` field? And, if that's possible, the `null` check should be the first thing to check. Because, if it can be `null` then your app will certainly crash, since you're testing for `equals()` on a `null` object before the `null` check!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of these code,

```
if(phoneNo.equals(" ") || phoneNo == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Enter the number !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Try following code,

// Trim the variable

```
phoneNo=txtPhoneNo.getText().toString().trim();
```

// Then condition part

```
if(phoneNo.length() == 0 && phoneNo != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Enter the number !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Comment: 'phoneNo.length() == 0 && phoneNo == null' did you mean '||'?
This code can be replaced with 'TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNo)'

Comment: @lassana, opps I mean != null

Comment: @Vigbyor, you should first check for null: if (phoneNo != null && phoneNo.length() == 0)

Answer (score 1):

To do this no need to take String and pass the content of edit-text into string. You can directly check by following code.

```
           if(txtPhoneNo.length()<=0) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Enter the number !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
            MyAsync ma = new MyAsync();
            ma.execute();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try something more, don't check validation on click button.
Do it before with: *TextWatcher*

Your activity implements android.text.TextWatcher interface
You add TextChanged listeners to you EditText boxes

```
txt1.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

Of the overridden methods, you could use the afterTextChanged(Editable s) method as follows:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// validation code goes here
}
```

You could directly check the contents of the EditText boxes like

```
String txt1String = txt1.getText().toString();
// Validate txt1String
```